# I'm trying to call a Javascriptcript method in a class from another class and I get error

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, constructor

I'm trying to call a Javascriptcript method in a class from another class and I get an error

```
error
{ error: 'slackService.getAccessData is not a function' }
```

***In the slackController.js below I called the method from slackServices.js saying***
**`slackService.getAccessData(code)`**

Find my slackcontroller.js below

```
import slackService from "../services/SlackService.js"

class SlackController {
  async handleCallback(req, res) {
    try {
      const code = req.query.code;
      console.log(code);
      if (code) {
        const { email, userData } = await slackService.getAccessData(code);

    const { slack_user_id } = userData;
  res.redirect("/")
   }  else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log("error")
  console.log({error: e.message});
  res.json({ error: e.message });
  
}
```

}
}

export default new SlackController();

find my slackService.js below

```
import Client from './WebClient.js';
import config from '../config/slack.js';
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';

class SlackService {
  async getAccessData(code) {
    const data = await this.getAccessToken(code);
    const user = await this.getUserInfo({ 
      token: data.access_token, user_id: data.authed_user.id 
    });
    
    console.log(data, user);
    return this.format(data, user);
    
  }

  async getUserInfo({ token, user_id }) {
    const wc = new Client(token);
    const { user } = await wc.users.info({ user: user_id });
    return user;
  }

  async getAccessToken (code) {
    const wc = new Client();
    // return await wc.accessToken(config(code));
    return await wc.accessToken(code);
  }
  }
}
export default SlackService;
```

Comment: Instead of exporting the class export an instance of the class. you can't call none static methods from a class without instantiating it first.

Comment: The service would be null as you dont instantiate it

Comment: I didnt get that, you mean "I can call none static method"? @JarneKompier

Comment: If instead of doing `export default SlackService` you do `export defualt slackService = new SlackService();` it should work I believe.

Comment: OK, can someone please tell me how to instantiate it? @Vince,

Comment: To instantiate a class you use `const name = new ClassName()`

Comment: @enCouder see the comment from Jarne Kompier

Comment: `export defualt slackService = new SlackService();`

I use that it worked!!! Thanks so much @JarneKompier

Comment: I've always used this platform like a google searching. It's my first time bringing a personal question and I'm so wowed and the response and love. 
Loads of love guys